# Confused about an integral from MIT integration bee 2012

Tags: calculus

One of the integrals is:

$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2+2\sin x + \cos x}\, \mathrm{d}x $$

How can there be two $\mathrm{d}x$?

[MIT's Integration Bee](http://web.mit.edu/abhinavk/www/integrationbee/)

Comment: It's a "typo"... (one I sometimes make)

Comment: @DavidMitra Well, its from MIT and I thought maybe it was some strange high level math, or it was a typo.  It's is a fun list of integrals to practice my skill one.

Comment: It is a 'typo', definitely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The extra $dx$ is definitely a typo. To solve this integral we have to substitute $u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$. Then, $\sin x=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}$, $\cos x=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$ and $dx=\frac{du}{1+u^2}$. Thus,
$$\int\frac{dx}{2+2\sin x+\cos x}=\int\frac{du}{2+2u^2+4u+1-u^2}=\int\frac{du}{u^2+4u+3}=\int\frac{du}{(u-1)(u-3)}=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{1-u}+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{u-3}=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|1-u\right|+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|u-3\right|+c=\\
\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|1-\tan\frac{ x}{2}\right|+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\tan\frac{ x}{2}-3\right|+c$$